# How to check time range

Tags: vb.net

I implmented a function to check time range in vb.net. But it is giving me wrong output.
My starttime is everyday at 11.00 Pm and end Time is 5.00 AM. My function if i pass 1.10 AM does not return me true output as this falls under that time range. Not sure what iam doing wrong.

```
Private Function CheckTimeRange() As Boolean
  Dim retValue As Boolean = True
  Try
    Dim Dt As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    Dim StartDt As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime("11.00 PM")
    Dim EndDt As DateTime =  Convert.ToDateTime("5.00 AM")

    Dim startTime As New TimeSpan(StartDt.Hour, StartDt.Minute, 0)
    Dim endTime As New TimeSpan(EndDt.Hour, EndDt.Minute, 0)
    Dim now As TimeSpan = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay

    If (now > startTime) AndAlso (now < endTime) Then
      retValue = True
    Else
      retValue = False
    End If
    Return retValue
  Catch ex As Exception
  End Try
End Function
```

Comment: Are you sure you're not running into an exception? I couldn't parse Convert.ToDateTime("11.00 PM") with either en-GB nor en-US format providers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you're overcomplicating your code. You could do:

```
Private Function CheckTimeRange() As Boolean
    Return DateTime.Now.Hour >= 23 OrElse DateTime.Now.Hour < 5
End Function
```

**Edit:**

If the start and end times are entered by the user, you should first convert the string values into `TimeSpan` objects, then you could use a more flexible method which takes date, min time and max time as parameters:

```
Private Function CheckTimeRange(myDate As DateTime, minTime as TimeSpan, maxTime As TimeSpan) As Boolean
    If minTime > maxTime Then
        Return myDate.TimeOfDay >= minTime OrElse myDate.TimeOfDay < maxTime
    Else
        Return myDate.TimeOfDay >= minTime AndAlso myDate.TimeOfDay < maxTime
    End If
End Function
```

Example usage:

```
Dim minTime As New TimeSpan(23, 0, 0) 'Should be converted from 11.00 PM
Dim maxTime As New TimeSpan(5, 0, 0) 'Should be converted from 5.00 AM
CheckTimeRange(New Date(2012, 1, 1, 15, 0, 0), minTime, maxTime) '==> false
CheckTimeRange(New Date(2012, 1, 1, 22, 30, 0), minTime, maxTime) '==> false
CheckTimeRange(New Date(2012, 1, 1, 23, 00, 0), minTime, maxTime) '==> true
CheckTimeRange(New Date(2012, 1, 2, 1, 10, 0), minTime, maxTime) '==> true
CheckTimeRange(New Date(2012, 1, 2, 4, 59, 0), minTime, maxTime) '==> true
CheckTimeRange(New Date(2012, 1, 2, 5, 10, 0), minTime, maxTime) '==> false
```

If you have trouble converting string values to TimeSpan you should ask a new question for this specific task.

Comment: Thanks for the help.But sometimes time can be entered as 11.30, 1.30 etc. How should account in those situations.

Comment: But the problem is they are specifying 11.00 PM and 5.00 AM. 11.00 PM is today and 5.00 AM will next day. Not quite sure how will get those two dates. The function is always getting me same date.

Comment: My function only compares the time of day, and accounts for the case where the end time is the next day. Try it! I will add example usage.

Comment: Sorry for late reply but your solution worked. Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

You're working with TimeSpan objects, and you'll find that 1.10 AM is never greater than 11.00pm without the date.

Meta-Knight has the better solution.